# regex to drop the last "0" and drop any zeros at the start of the string

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like

```
1) "CAP07560" 
2) "CAP41060" 
3) "CAP43500"
4) "CAP22390"
```

I want to first drop the text `"CAP"` from string and then for the remaining string I want to drop the last "0" and drop any zeros at the start of the string.

So my output will be:

```
1) "756" 
2) "4106" 
3) "4350"
4) "2239"
```

I tried the following-

```
public class RegexTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // drop the last "0" and then drop any 
        // zeros at the start of the remaining number. 
        String str = "CAP07560";
        String pattern = "^CAP[ 0]*|( |(?<!\\d))*$";
        str = str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

My OUTPUT: `7560`

So my output is `7560` but it should be `756`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use alternation to do this in single `replaceAll` call:

```
str = str.replacAll("^CAP0*|0$", "");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T9wVj0/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^CAP0*`: Match `CAP` followed by 0 or more zeroes at the start
- `|`: OR
- `0$`: Match last zero